# Laravel 8: Array to string conversion while trying to run php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have downloaded a project of Laravel and I wanted to run the project by typing `php artisan serve` but I get this error:

> **ErrorException**
>
> Array to string conversion

But now the problem is, I don't know where this error is coming from and how can I debug!

Here is a capture of it:

[image: capture]

So would you just tell me from where I can start debugging and which part of project returns this error (models, controllers, migrations or etc)...

**Web.php**:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $threads = App\Models\Thread::paginate(15);
    return view('welcome', compact('threads'));
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::resource('/thread', App\Http\Controllers\ThreadController::class);

Route::resource('/thread/mark-as-solution', [App\Http\Controllers\ThreadController::class, 'markAsSolution'])->name('markAsSolution');

Route::resource('comment', App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::class,['only' => ['update','destroy']]);

Route::post('comment/create/{thread}', [App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::class, 'addThreadComment'])->name('threadcomment.store');

Route::post('reply/create/{comment}', [App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::class, 'addReplyComment'])->name('replycomment.store');

Route::post('comment/like', [App\Http\Controllers\LikeController::class, 'likeIt'])->name('likeIt');
```

Comment: It looks like you code wrongly in routes/web.php file, you can show me it

Comment: @ChungNguyễnTrần I just added it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
Route::resource('/thread/mark-as-solution', [App\Http\Controllers\ThreadController::class, 'markAsSolution'])->name('markAsSolution');
```

Here you should edit to get / post / put / patch / delete

Ex:

```php
Route::get('/thread/mark-as-solution', [App\Http\Controllers\ThreadController::class, 'markAsSolution'])->name('markAsSolution');
```